# Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm doing a logout function right now in Meteor and I noticed something wierd. When I'm on my login page or even when logging out and redirected to login page there is an error on my Google console:

Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

Here's my code:

`router.js`

```
var routerExcepts = [
  "login",
  "register"
];


Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (Router.current().route.getName() != "adminlogin.:_id") {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      return this.redirect("/login");
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  }
}, {
  except: routerExcepts
});
```

`home.html:`

```
<template name="home">
  <div class="container">
     <a href="#" id="item-logout" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Logout</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

`home.js:`

```
Template.home.events({
  "click #item-logout": function() {
    Meteor.logout();
  }
});
```

Does anybody have an idea what's going on with my code? I know this is kind of duplicate to other questions and I tried the solutions offered on those answered questions but it doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set this as a return value, I think this may be causing your issues, Replace

`return this.redirect("/login");`

with

`this.redirect("/login");`

If you are still getting the error then try replacing 'this.redirect' with 'Router.go' (which, if I remember correctly, this.redirect proxies under the hood anyway) as below:

`Router.go("/login");`

You could also remove the else to ensure that the this.next() is always fired:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (Router.current().route.getName() != "adminlogin.:_id") {
    if (!Meteor.userId())
      Router.go("/login");
    this.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, I've tried doing what you told me to but still did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a repro in github?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `this.next()` outside of your conditional:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (Router.current().route.getName() != "adminlogin.:_id") {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      return this.redirect("/login");
    }
  }
  this.next();
}
```